# Is this a valid PERCENTILE_CONT SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentile, percentile-cont

I am trying to run a SQL query to find a 50th percentile in a table within a certain group, but then i am also grouping the result over the same field. Here is my query, for example over the tpch's nation table:

```
SELECT 
   regionkey,
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY regionkey)
FROM "tpch/nation"
GROUP BY regionkey
ORDER BY regionkey
```

Is this a valid query? I am trying to QA my code by running all kinds of different percentile queries. Postgres returns this result for the above query,:

```
 regionkey    | percentile_cont 
 -------------+-----------------
            0 |               0
            1 |               1
            2 |               2
            3 |               3
            4 |               4
 (5 rows)
```

But my question is in the real world, would someone would try to run such type of queries? I am new to aggregate functions, specially the percentile functions.

Comment: It is a valid query in that it runs.  It is not a valid query in that the results are unstable and don't really mean anything.  Sample data and desired results would help.  It is not clear what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `percentile_cont()` to get a percentage of some ordered value.  For instance, if you had a `population` column for the region, then you would calculate the median population as:

```
SELECT regionkey,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY population)
FROM "tpch/nation"
GROUP BY regionkey
ORDER BY regionkey;
```

Using `regionkey` in the `ORDER BY` is non-sensical.  Within each group, `regionkey` has only one value.  Hence, the `PERCENTILE_CONT()` can only return that value.

However, it can be quite useful with almost any other column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is exactly the answer i wanted to double check and verify. Even though the query is non-sensicle, it is still a valid SQL syntactically, and should return the correct results as expected. I am just trying to test my system if it supports all the valid SQL, sensicle or not.